# some profile informations like youtube link doesnt seem

Tags: functions

youtube icon which is represented in code with "fa fa-youtube" doesnt seem but i have youtube link on my profile settings.

```
 <?php  $youtube_profile = get_the_author_meta( 'youtube_profile' );
            if ( $youtube_profile && $youtube_profile != '' ) {
                echo '<span class="fa fa-youtube"><a href="'.esc_url($youtube_profile).'"  ></a></span> ';
            }?>
```

Comment: depends on wich fontawesome version you have. Try with "fab fa-youtube".

Comment: gregory24 no, when i remove "if ...", it seem.but i need all code with now form

Comment: does link show ? you just said, icon don't show !

Comment: i found the source of error.it is about functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reply to gregory24 isn't really explicit enough I'm afraid..

The reason you can display a FontAwesome icon without the if statement is only because this html `<span class="fa fa-youtube">...</span>` is loaded into the DOM of you page meanwhile your `$youtube_profile` variable is likely containing some value but your statement is wrong.

this should work if `$youtube_profile` isn't empty:

```
<?php  
$youtube_profile = get_the_author_meta( 'youtube_profile' );

if ( !empty($youtube_profile) || $youtube_profile != '' ) {
    echo '<span class="fa fa-youtube"><a href="'.esc_url($youtube_profile).'"></a</span> ';
}
?>
```

BUT.. 
you don't need to check twice for the same thing:
`!empty($youtube_profile)` AND `$youtube_profile != ''` checks are the same

the most simple way would be to simply check it like this, no need of checking if not FALSE just check if TRUE

`if ( $youtube_profile ) { ... }`

Comment: i changed the code with yours but there is no changing.i think maybe there is only one link form for wp profile inputs and i enter links as wrong.do you have idea?

Comment: the author meta you want to get "youtube_profile" isn't a WP core meta for users, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/#description
you must have this as a function in your theme to extend the default WP author meta.
On the same page above you can see an example:
    the_author_meta( 'display_name', 25 ); where 25 is the ID of this user. so maybe simply try parsing your user ID the same way with you meta-tag for youtube profile url